# How do I get a folder tree view in the left column of the Finder?

Tags: finder, folders

I'd like to have a tree view of my current folder (it's children and it's parents) for navigation in the left column of the finder's UI. How do I get that?

Comment: This site works better with one question per question. I've removed the second question from your post, please ask it separately if necessary.

Comment: @patrix, I'm curious, does it actually say anywhere in the rules only "one question per question"?

Comment: @user3439894 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post lists some good reasons for this

Comment: @patrix, Thanks, the accepted answer made good points.

Answer (score 11):

`Favorites` in the left hand side is a flat list, but it's a good place to store some frequent destinations.

And make sure to select the third option (circled) so you can have a tree structure in your Finder.

Last but not least, you may notice that the screenshot has a `Path Bar` at the bottom indicating your current location in the hierarchy. And I think this is the closest thing if you are asking for a Windows Explorer type layout. Enable it in the Finder menu: View->Show Path Bar

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In OS X’s Finder, the key combination <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> arranges the view in column (tree) fashion.

If you wish to add the folder to the Finder’s ***sidebar***, simply drag and drop the folder into it under the “Favorites” designation.

If you wish to make the column view the default view for that folder, use the key combination  <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> with the desired folder selected and then check the option `always open [browse] in column view.`

Comment: It sounds like the user is asking for a Windows Explorer type layout (unless I misunderstood)which that will not do and is not available in the Finder.. There are, however, 3rd party Finder "replacements/enhancements" that might give you the layout you crave. A search on macupdate.com might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has a list of folders on the left side (with `>` greater-than signs to open them, revealing any child folders inside), and a list of files on the right side.

Finder keeps a list of favorites on the left side, and combines the folder tree view you're asking for with the list of files on the right: if you select List View (menu option `View > as List`) *and* have Grouping turned off (`View > Show View Options`, set `Group By` to `None`), it will display the list of folders and files, and allow you to open folders by clicking the little `>` next to them.  You can do this with child folders as well.

If you want folders to show up at the top of the list (as they do in Windows), that option is in `Finder > Settings... > Advanced > Keep folders on top`.

Note that Windows 11 (and maybe 10?) Explorer is starting to act more and more like Finder: It, too, can have a list of Favorites on the left, and a tree view of folders plus files on the right.